# Powershell Script to remove disabled accounts from groups runs slow. How to make it faster?

Tags: powershell, performance

My code:

```
$searchOU = "OU=a,OU=b,OU=c,OU=d,OU=e,DC=f,DC=g,DC=com"
Get-ADGroup -Filter 'GroupCategory -eq "Security"' -SearchBase $searchOU | sort name | ForEach- Object{
  $group = $_
  Get-ADGroupMember -Identity $group | Get-ADUser | Where-Object { $_.Enabled -eq $false} | ForEach-Object{
      $user = $_
      $uname = $user.Name
      $gname = $group.Name
      Write-Host "Removing $uname from $gname" -Foreground Yellow
      Remove-ADGroupMember -Identity $group -Member $user -Confirm:$false #-whatif
  }
}
```

It runs, but it's dog slow.  Any suggestions on ways to make it run faster?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to remember that `Get-ADGroupMember` can return users, groups, and computers, not just user objects..
If you want to search for **user** objects only, you need to add a Where-Object clause there.

Unfortunately, while `Get-ADUser` has a `-Filter` parameter that enables you to find disabled users much more quickly than filtering afterwards on the collection of users, using a filter while piping user DN's to it will totally **ignore** the pipeline and collect **all** users that are disabled..
So, in this case, we're stuck with appending a Where-Object clause.

You could change your code to rule out all objects from `Get-ADGroupMember` that are not uders:

```
$searchOU = "OU=a,OU=b,OU=c,OU=d,OU=e,DC=f,DC=g,DC=com"
Get-ADGroup -Filter "GroupCategory -eq 'Security'" -SearchBase $searchOU | Sort-Object Name | ForEach-Object {
    $group = $_
    Get-ADGroupMember -Identity $group | Where-Object { $_.objectClass -eq 'user' } | 
    Get-ADUser | Where-Object { $_.Enabled -eq $false} | ForEach-Object {
        Write-Host "Removing $($_.Name) from $($group.Name)" -Foreground Yellow
        Remove-ADGroupMember -Identity $group -Member $_ -Confirm:$false #-whatif
    }
}
```

The above removes one disabled user at a time and for each of them writes a line on the console.
You could make it work faster if you can cope with getting a different output on screen like this:

```
$searchOU = "OU=a,OU=b,OU=c,OU=d,OU=e,DC=f,DC=g,DC=com"
$result = foreach ($group in (Get-ADGroup -Filter "GroupCategory -eq 'Security'" -SearchBase $searchOU)) {
    $users = Get-ADGroupMember -Identity $group | Where-Object { $_.objectClass -eq 'user' } | 
             Get-ADUser | Where-Object { $_.Enabled -eq $false}
    if ($users) {
        # the Remove-ADGroupMember cmdlet can take an array of users to remove at once
        Remove-ADGroupMember -Identity $group -Member $users -Confirm:$false #-whatif
        # output an object that gets collected in variable $result
        [PsCustomObject]@{Group = $group.Name; RemovedUsers = ($users.Name -join '; ')}
    }
}

# if you like, output to console as table
$result | Sort-Object Group | Format-Table -AutoSize -Wrap

# or write to CSV file
$result | Export-Csv -Path 'D:\Test\RemovedUsers.csv' -NoTypeInformation
```

Comment: WOW!  That runs at least 5 X faster!  Thank you so much!

Comment: Well, it runs faster, but it's parsing through disabled accounts that are not in the group.  It seems like it's finding disable accounts in the domain, then removing them even though they aren't in the groups.  I'm trying to find disable accounts specifically in the groups in the OU, then remove them.

Comment: @DanielGower Damn... Nowhere in the docs is written that the `-Filter` parameter makes  Get-ADUser ignore what is sent through the pipeline.. I have edited the code now and reluctantly re-introduced a Where-Object clause.. It won't be 5x faster than your original now, but perhaps still enough to be workable for you..

Comment: Excellent script thank you,  is it possible to add conditions if the account is disabled for more than 30 days remove it otherwise leave it.

Comment: How can I add conditions if the account is disabled for x days than remove it from the group.

Comment: @mohamednur Well, that isn't as easy as it may seem. To figure out when a user was disabled, please see [this question (and the answers)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/70955498/9898643)