# How to find users who were disabled specific dates

Tags: powershell, active-directory, user-accounts

Could someone help me find disabled accounts from AD within a specific timeframe?

For example, I can run a script that shows me the last 30 days, 60 , 90 whatever

```
Search-ADAccount -SearchBase "DC=A,DC=B,DC=C,DC=X" -AccountDisabled -UsersOnly | Get-ADUser -Properties whenChanged | Where whenChanged -gt (Get-Date).AddDays(-60) | Export-CSV “C:\Disabledusers60.CSV” –NoTypeInformation
```

The problem is that this way I would see the present ones from January 2022 as well, and my idea is to be able to run a specific date, so in the end of February to have a list of disabled users between 1st of December- 31th of Dec. Then on March to have the list from 1st of January till 31th January and so on.

That way will not pull out from AD last 60 days including the disabled accounts from the current month.

Sorry for the big thread explanation, hopefully, someone could bring some light here.

Comment: Just remember that looking at `whenChanged` only tells you went the account was last modified, not necessarily when the account was disabled. But I assume you're ok with that. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58938603/1202807) is slightly more accurate in determining when it was disabled, but there really is no way to know with 100% certainty when the account was disabled.

Comment: This depends on whether you're looking for users where their `AccountExpirationDate` simply expired (you can check those) or whether you need to find accounts that did not expire because that date was reached, but instead were manually disabled by an admin. In both cases, this has little to do with the `Modified` (whenChanged) attribute

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should give you a list of AD Users which are **Disabled** and their **WhenChanged** attribute is **between** the first and last day of the Month.

```
$today = [datetime]::Today
$firstDay = [datetime]::new($today.Year, $today.Month, 1, 0, 0, 0)
$lastDay = $firstDay.AddMonths(1).AddSeconds(-1)

$params = @{
    SearchBase = 'OU=Finance,OU=UserAccounts,DC=FABRIKAM,DC=COM'
    Properties = 'whenChanged'
    LDAPFilter = -join @(
        '(&'
            '(userAccountControl:1.2.840.113556.1.4.803:=2)'
            '(whenChanged>={0:yyyyMMddHHmmss.0Z})' -f $firstDay
            '(whenChanged<={0:yyyyMMddHHmmss.0Z})' -f $lastDay
        ')'
    )
}

Get-ADUser @params | Export-Csv ...
```

If you need to query a different time range you would need to update the variables `$firstDay` and `$lastDay`, for example, for **September 2021**:

```
$firstDay = [datetime]::new(2021, 9, 1, 0, 0, 0)
$lastDay = [datetime]::new(2021, 10, 1, 0, 0, 0).AddSeconds(-1)
# 10 => Being the next Month and .AddSeconds(-1) for
# the last second of the Previous Month (9)
# If this was for the Month of December:
# [datetime]::new(2022, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0).AddSeconds(-1)
```

Comment: This is nearly the most accurate way to get the desired information. It is possible for Domain Admins to go even further by getting the last modification date and time of a specific attribute (userAccountControl in this case) with the repadmin tool or the equivalent Powershell cmdlets (Get-ADReplicationAttributeMetadata -> userAccountControl -> LastOriginatingChangeTime)

Comment: I will try this option and see what results I`m gathering. Much appreciated for your help!

Comment: @SantiagoSquarzon thank you very much! I have the listed accounts. Your solution did resolve the issue. If you have time maybe you can explain a bit your script or how did you found such a great solution? :) Much appreciatted.

Comment: @MRM. happy to help. This article should help you learn if you want to understand LDAP Filter https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/5392.active-directory-ldap-syntax-filters.aspx, aside from that there is nothing complicated about this script. Get the First Day and Last Day of the Month and store them in a variable and then use the filter capabilities of `Get-ADuser`

Answer (score 3):

As commented, the `whenChanged` attribute does not necessarily be the date and time a user was disabled, because there could have been other modifications to the user account afterwards.

How about probing the windows Event log for event **4725** (==> a user account was disabled) ?

Thanks to [ZivkoK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70955498/how-to-find-users-who-were-disabled-specific-dates/70959219?noredirect=1#comment125443862_70959219), who commented that events are not replicated across Domain Controllers, you need to loop over all of them to get the results

```
# example timeframe December 2021
$startTime = [datetime]'12/1/2021'
$endTime   = $startTime.AddMonths(1).AddDays(-1)
$filter    = @{LogName='Security';ProviderName='Microsoft-Windows-Security-Auditing';ID=4725;StartTime=$startTime;EndTime=$endTime }
$DCs       = (Get-ADDomainController -filter *).Name  # or HostName for fqdn

$result = foreach ($dc in $DCs) {
    # you may need to use the -Credential parameter on Get-WinEvent
    # to supply the credentials of a domain administrator
    Get-WinEvent -FilterHashtable $filter -ComputerName $dc | ForEach-Object {
        # convert the event to XML and grab the Event node
        $eventXml   = ([xml]$_.ToXml()).Event
        $userName   = ($eventXml.EventData.Data | Where-Object { $_.Name -eq 'TargetUserName' }).'#text'
        $userSID    = ($eventXml.EventData.Data | Where-Object { $_.Name -eq 'TargetSid' }).'#text'
        $userDomain = ($eventXml.EventData.Data | Where-Object { $_.Name -eq 'TargetDomainName' }).'#text'
        # output the properties you need
        [PSCustomObject]@{
            UserName   = $userName
            UserSID    = $userSID
            UserDomain = $userDomain
            Disabled   = [DateTime]$eventXml.System.TimeCreated.SystemTime
        }
    }
}

# output on screen
$result | Format-Table -AutoSize  # or use Out-GridView if you prefer

# output to CSV file
$outFile = 'X:\DisabledUsers_{0:MMM-yyyy}.csv' -f $startTime
$result | Export-Csv -Path $outFile -NoTypeInformation
```

Comment: Nice solution. Just wanted to add that the events are not replicated across Domain Controllers, so you have to get them from all DCs in the domain to have a full list. Also events may be deleted over time depending on the settings (i.e Max Log Size Reached). Finally, you need Domain Admin privileges to access the Security logs on a DC.

Comment: @ZivkoK Thanks for these remarks. I have edited my answer to now loop over the Domain Controllers and have added a comment on the `-Credential` parameter.

Comment: Guys,I will try this option and see what results I`m gathering. Much appreciated for your help!

Comment: I have a bunch of errors, obv I think -Cred are not there so require to run the script from a DC server or with my PS session will be enough?Get-WinEvent : The RPC server is unavailable
 ![Here are the results](https://ibb.co/2KKh02p)

Comment: @MRM. That error has to do with your computer not being able to communicate with one or more remote systems. Perhaps the tips [here](https://www.drivereasy.com/knowledge/rpc-server-is-unavailable-error-on-windows-10-fixed/) can help you.