# Finding an Expired AD User since the start of the year with Powershell

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I am preparing for an audit and trying to get our data via PowerShell, which I am a noob to.
I am using the `Search-ADAccount` command to list our Expired AD users, I now have to show the Expired users which were active in the last twelve months

I am aware I can use the Filter switch with `Get-ADUser`, but can not seem to get it to work with `Search-ADAccount`.

```
#Expired users
$Filename = "BJL Expired Users.csv"
Search-ADAccount -UsersOnly  -AccountExpired -filter {WhenChanged -ge '${StartDate} '} –ResultSetSize $null |  Select-Object Name, SamAccountName, DistinguishedName, mail, lastlogondate,Enabled,lockedOut,whenChanged,AccountExpirationDate,UserAccountControl,whenCreated| Export-CSV -path "$($ExportPath)$($Filename)"  –NoTypeInformation|out-gridview -title "Expired Accounts"
```

The `-filter` switch does not exist in `Search-ADAccount` how do I do this with `Search-ADAccount`

references https://shellgeek.com/powershell-search-adaccount-cmdlet-examples/
[How to find users who were disabled specific dates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70955498/how-to-find-users-who-were-disabled-specific-dates)

Comment: Use `Get-ADUser` instead. You have already stated it, `Search-ADAccount` doesn't have a `-Filter`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you have already stated, [`Search-ADAccount`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/activedirectory/search-adaccount?view=windowsserver2022-ps) doesn't have a `-Filter` parameter, you need to use [`Get-ADUser`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/activedirectory/get-aduser?view=windowsserver2022-ps) in this case and construct the filter yourself.

This example uses an LDAP Filter to find users which's `whenChanged` attribute is is greater than or equal to 1 year ago and its `accountExpires` attribute is lower than now (UTC), meaning, the account is expired. For a better understanding of LDAP syntax you can check [**Active Directory: LDAP Syntax Filters**](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/5392.active-directory-ldap-syntax-filters.aspx).

```bash
$properties = @(
    'Name'
    'SamAccountName'
    'DistinguishedName'
    'mail'
    'lastlogondate'
    'Enabled'
    'lockedOut'
    'whenChanged'
    'AccountExpirationDate'
    'UserAccountControl'
    'whenCreated'
)

$filter = -join @(
    '(&'                                                                            # AND, all conditions must be met
        '(whenChanged>={0:yyyyMMddHHmmss.0Z})' -f [datetime]::UtcNow.AddYears(-1)   # `whenChanged` attribute is greater than or equal to 1 year ago
        '(!accountExpires>={0})' -f [datetime]::UtcNow.ToFileTimeUtc()              # `accountExpires` attribute is lower than now (UTC), meaning, the account is expired
    ')'                                                                             # close AND clause
)

$result = Get-ADUser -LDAPFilter $filter -Properties $properties |
    Select-Object $properties
$result | Export-Csv -Path "$($ExportPath)$($Filename)" -NoTypeInformation
$result | Out-GridView -Title 'Expired Accounts'
```