# Trying to find active AD users for the last 12 months (LDAP Filter with Get-ADUser Powershell)

Tags: powershell, active-directory

Hi see this question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77558357/finding-an-expired-ad-user-since-the-start-of-the-year-with-powershell/77558614#77558614) This question is a follow up to the linked question

Using the references to LDAP filter in the linked question.  I tried to look for active users by combining `WhenChanged` is greater than 1 year ago and `LastLogon` is greater than 1 year again however I am struggling with the syntax

I have used the call to look at the properties for the AD User

```
Get-ADUser -Filter "Name -eq '<user name>'" -Properties * | Get-Member
```

The filter I have tried

```
$filter = -join @(
    '(&'                                                                            # AND, all conditions must be met
        '(whenChanged>={0:yyyyMMddHHmmss.0Z})' -f [datetime]::UtcNow.AddYears(-1)   # `whenChanged` attribute is greater than or equal to 1 year ago
        '(LastLogonDate>={0:yyyyMMddHHmmss.0Z})' -f [datetime]::UtcNow.AddYears(-1) # `lastlogondate` attribute is greater than now (UTC), meaning, logged on this year
    ')'                                                                             # close AND clause
)
```

The full code is

```
$timespan = New-Timespan -Days (Get-Date).DayOfYear
$StartDate = (Get-Date).AddDays((Get-Date).DayOfYear*-1).ToString("dd/MM/yyyy")

$properties = @(
    'displayName'
    'title'
    'department'
    'DistinguishedName'
    'mail'
    'lastlogondate'
    'Enabled'
    'lockedOut'
    'whenChanged'
    'AccountExpirationDate'
    'UserAccountControl'
    'sAMAccountType'
    'whenCreated'
)

$filter = -join @(
    '(&'                                                                            # AND, all conditions must be met
        '(whenChanged>={0:yyyyMMddHHmmss.0Z})' -f [datetime]::UtcNow.AddYears(-1)   # `whenChanged` attribute is greater than or equal to 1 year ago
        '(LastLogonDate>={0:yyyyMMddHHmmss.0Z})' -f [datetime]::UtcNow.AddYears(-1) # `lastlogondate` attribute is greater than now (UTC), meaning, logged on this year
    ')'                                                                             # close AND clause
)
$Filename ="BJL Active Users.csv"
$result = Get-ADUser -LDAPFilter $filter -Properties $properties |
    Select-Object $properties
$result | Export-Csv -Path "$($ExportPath)$($Filename)" -NoTypeInformation
$result | Out-GridView -Title 'Active Accounts'
```

Comment: Use this filter `$filter = "(&(whenChanged>=$([datetime]::UtcNow.AddYears(-1).ToString('yyyyMMddHHmmss.0Z')))(LastLogon>=$([datetime]::UtcNow.AddYears(-1).ToFileTimeUtc())))"`  I prefer `lastLogon` rather than `LastLogonDate`, the first one is the true ActiveDirectory attribute and stored as long, the later is a constructed attribute by the `Get-ADUser` cmdlet.

Comment: I'd suggest you use [`lastLogonTimestamp`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/adschema/a-lastlogontimestamp) instead of `lastLogon`. The `lastLogon` attribute is not replicated and is only updated when a user authenticates to that specific domain controller. If a user somehow only ever authenticates to one DC and you read from another, then you will get a wildly inaccurate date. `lastLogonTimestamp` is guaranteed to be accurate within 2 weeks. Of course, this is a moot point if your domain only has one DC.